# lilo: Fatal: raid_setup: stat("/dev/nvme0n1")

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, boot, lilo

I have booted Debian Live CD, and I am trying to create lilo boot record on my disk

The disk partition is mounted as /mnt/root and has the linux kernel and /etc/lilo.conf:

```
boot=/dev/nvme0n1
root=/dev/nvme0n1p1
map=/boot/map

lba32

prompt
timeout=30

default=linux

image=/boot/vmlinuz
    label=linux
    read-only
    append="rootfstype=ext4 net.ifnames=0 loglevel=4 3"
```

the mounted partition has all the system files and the kernel image. I am not using any raid, although the debian live CD for some  reason loads all md_raid modules.

How can I create boot record on my disk?

Comment: Trying to setup your system to boot via Lilo is a bit surprising in 2023; the Lilo developers asked to stop using it in 2015. I'm honestly a bit surprised it still works, nice!

Comment: So the question here becomes, seeing your system correctly handles NVMe as nvme and not just some disk emulation, whether your system still supports the forty years old legacy MBR Boot with boot records, or whether just dropping the UEFI shim file that loads Lilo into the fat32 ESP is enough.